# Grails 2.3.8 isn't working with external configuration

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm running a test with Grails 2.3.8 and an external configuration, yet the value doesn't seem to be coming through.  I've tried this in older versions and am not seeing the same error.  Did something change or am I missing something that I fat fingered?  I am using an absolute path and the file definitely exists because Grails sees the key.

*Config.groovy*

```
reliable.string = "This string is working"
grails.config.locations = ["file:/home/howes/Project/project/test-config.groovy"]
```

*/home/howes/Project/project/test-config.groovy*

```
test.externalstring = "this is a test"
```

To test it I made a controller and just called grailsApplication to pull out the values.  The first time I load the page I get a blank map, and when I refresh I see the key but no value.  To make sure I am pulling everything correctly I am outputting the test-config.groovy item and one from the basic Config.groovy.

*TestContoller.groovy*

```
class TestController {
def grailsApplication
def index() {
    println grailsApplication.config.test
    println grailsApplication.config.reliable
    return [ext:grailsApplication.config.test.externalstring, ext2:grailsApplication.config.reliable.string]
    }
}
```

*Console Output (First Load)*

```
[:]
[string:This string is working]
```

*Console Output (Page Refresh)*

```
[externalstring:[:]]
[string:This string is working]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This works as expected when I test on a windows machine.

Comment: I can reliably recreate this error in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Howes It might be a permissions issues so its not seeing external file at all. The page will show the key on refresh because you are trying to access it via the index return statement the first time doesn't show the key since it probably isn't see the external config file.